# Contractively complemented subspaces of $c_0(I)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Does every contractively complemented subspace of $c_0(I)$ is isometric to $c_0(J)$ for some $J\subseteq I$?

May be someone has a counterexample?

Comment: "Has" is correct; "have" is not. (So I have rolled back your change)

Comment: Why did not not correct the other three mistakes, Yemon? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is true, but I don't know where it is proved in the literature. The reason I say yes is that what you want is a corollary of a unpublished almost isometric theorem that Zippin proved in the 1970s! Here is either an outline of a proof or complete nonsense:  Let $P$ be  a contractive projection on $c_0(I)$. Then the range of $P^*$ is a sublattice of $\ell_1(I)$ (see H. Elton Lacey's book, Springer Grundlehren Band 208, The isometric theory of the classical Banach spaces) and hence is the norm closed span of a set $x_\alpha$ of disjointly supported unit vectors.  For each $\alpha$, compose $P^*$ with the restriction mapping $R_\alpha$ onto the support of $x_\alpha$ to get a weak$^*$ continuous contractive projection onto the span of $x_\alpha$. So there is $y_\alpha$ in $c_0(I)$ s.t. $R_\alpha P^* = x_\alpha\otimes y_\alpha$.  Argue that $(y_\alpha)_\alpha$ is 1-equivalent to the $c_0(J)$ basis for some $J$ and that the range of $P$ is the closed span of $(y_\alpha)_\alpha$

Notice that for this to happen each $x_\alpha$ must achieve its norm and thus has finite support.  Interestingly, the $y_\alpha$ need not have finite support.

Comment: Thank you sir! Could post in comments what was that theorem by Zippin?

Comment: A script $L_{\infty,\epsilon}$ subspace of $c_0$ is $f(\epsilon)$ isomorphic to $c_0$, where $f(\epsilon) \to 1$ as $\epsilon \to 0$.

Answer (score 2):

As you may know already, every contractively complemented subspace of $\ell_1(I)$ is isometric to $\ell_1(J)$ for some $J \subset I$ --- see for example Semadeni, Banach Spaces of Continuous Functions, 1971, p. 488.  This is just the dual of your desired proposition.  If $X$ is a contractively complemented subspace of $c_0(I)$ by a projection $P$, then the adjoint $P^*$ (as in Bill's answer above) is an isometric embedding of $X^*$ into $\ell_1(I)$ such that $P^*(X)$ is contractively complemented by the restriction operator, so that $P^*(X)$ is isometric to some $\ell_1(J)$.  Can you then argue by w*-continuity of the isometry that $X$ must be isometric to $c_0(J)$?

Comment: From your words it seems like a standard trick but I don't know it

Comment: Knowledge sometimes degrades over time.  Something "well known" 44 years ago may degrade to "known", then to "forgotten".

Comment: Have you confirmed the validity of the last sentence in my answer, stated as a question?

Comment: No I havn't, I really have no idea how to prove the last statement. It seems you need to know more about structure of $X^*$. But in this case, imho, one had to repeat Bill's argument.